# animated gif on uibutton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, gif, animated

I use this code, that work, really size of image 160x148 but image button is view very big on all screen!

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"button2.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"button3.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"button4.png"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[yourButton addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

How fix that?

Comment: Well its big because you called initWithFrame: and passed in your view's bounds. Change it to a different-sized rect.

Comment: Change self.view.bounds to CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 148) at least, and then reposition it to wherever you need it.

Comment: I'll repost as an answer then we can both get some rep :) Happy it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are big because you called `initWithFrame:` and passed in your view's bounds. Change it to a different-sized rect, such as:

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 148)
```

... and then reposition it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It will help you for correct solution.

```
 UIImage *myimage=UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png";
Button.imageview.image=myimage;
```